how to update nested data in prisma?
Before delving further, here's a brief overview of the technologies I'm using:

Next.Js(app router) version 14.2.2
React version 18
prisma version 5.12.1
database -> mongodb

I'm new to prisma, When I attempt to update nested data in Prisma, it always returns an error in the catch block with the error message like this:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') at PATCH ...
I'm pretty sure there's an error in this PATCH section but I don't know where it is, here's the code:
export const PATCH = async (
  req: NextRequest,
  { params }: { params: { id: string } }
) => {
  try {
    const { id } = params
    const body: ProductPostProps = await req.json()
    const { title, price, description, stock, categories, images } = body

    const updateProduct = await prisma.product.update({
      where: {
        id,
      },
      data: {
        title,
        price,
        description,
        stock,
        categories: {
          create: categories.map(({ title }) => ({
            title,
          })),
        },
        images: {
          create: images.map(({ image }) => ({
            image,
          })),
        },
      },
      include: {
        images: true,
        categories: true,
      },
    })

    if (!updateProduct) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        message: "data not found",
        status: 404,
      })
    }

    return NextResponse.json({
      message: "product updated",
    })
  } catch (error) {
    //error appear in this section
    console.log(error)
    return NextResponse.json({
      message: "internal server error",
      error,
      status: 500,
    })
  }
}

When I use the POST method to post nested data, it works fine. Here's an example:
export const POST = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  try {
    const body: ProductPostProps = await req.json()
    const { title, price, description, stock, categories, images } = body

    await prisma.product.create({
      data: {
        title,
        price,
        description,
        stock,
        categories: {
          create: categories.map(({ title }) => ({
            title,
          })),
        },
        images: {
          create: images.map(({ image }) => ({
            image,
          })),
        },
      },
      include: {
        images: true,
        categories: true,
      },
    })

    return NextResponse.json({
      message: "product successfully created",
      status: 201,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return NextResponse.json({
      message: "internal server error",
      error: error,
      status: 500,
    })
  }
}

And here's an example of the data when successfully posted:
{
      "id": "662672ede82c9e68a76f9b06",
      "title": "Nike Dunk Low Retro SE",
      "price": 1900000,
      "description": "The '80s b-ball icon returns with a classic construction and throwback hoops flair. Channelling vintage style back onto the streets, its padded, low-cut collar lets you take your game anywhere—in comfort.",
      "stock": 10,
      "createdAt": "2024-04-22T14:23:41.713Z",
      "updatedAt": "2024-04-22T14:23:41.713Z",
      "images": [
        {
          "id": "662672ede82c9e68a76f9b0a",
          "image": "https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_1728_v1/f_auto,q_auto:eco/6464f9e4-59af-4179-9c7f-e81d334db2aa/dunk-low-retro-se-shoes-tsMmHC.png",
          "productId": "662672ede82c9e68a76f9b06"
        },
        {
          "id": "662672ede82c9e68a76f9b0b",
          "image": "https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_1728_v1/f_auto,q_auto:eco/49f166a8-7ea5-4b64-b4a3-05fb4d420281/dunk-low-retro-se-shoes-tsMmHC.png",
          "productId": "662672ede82c9e68a76f9b06"
        },
      ],
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "662672ede82c9e68a76f9b07",
          "title": "men's shoes",
          "productId": "662672ede82c9e68a76f9b06"
        },
        {
          "id": "662672ede82c9e68a76f9b09",
          "title": "nike",
          "productId": "662672ede82c9e68a76f9b06"
        }
      ],
    },

And this is my Prisma data model:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
 
model Product {
  id          String         @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title       String
  price       Int
  images      ImageProduct[]
  description String?
  stock       Int?
  categories  Category[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@map("products")
}

model ImageProduct {
  id        String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  image     String?
  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  productId String

  @@map("image_products")
}

model Category {
  id        String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title     String
  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  productId String

  @@map("categories")
}


It's not a Prisma error, it's an error with incoming data.
Just like the error message says, either categories or images is undefined and which is why there's an exception thrown when you try to map it.
I would log the value of the request body and try to figure out why the client is not sending the expected data in its PATCH request.

A side note: PUT can be used to both create and update a resource. If you wish, you could replace POST and PATCH with a single PUT endpoint which takes an optional id param. You would use prisma.product.upsert which creates the product if either id is undefined or doesn't match an existing product; or updates an existing product with the id.
Here's the relevant documentation.

When I tried to update the data by inserting an image and category, it was successful. Thank you, that was very helpful. Also, thank you for the side note.

I'm glad you managed to fix this. Happy to help!
